# Nvidia drivers installation error (Package nvidia-dkms-460 is not configured yet)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dpkg, dkms

I'm trying to install `nvidia` drivers on my `Ubuntu 20.10` system. The problem is that they can't be installed. I have this problem for more than 14 days and I can't resolve it.

When I try to install them using "Software & Updates":

[image]

When I try to do that using cmd:

```
milano@milano-lenovo:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-460 is already the newest version (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.10.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-450
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-460 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.9.16-050916-generic
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-460.32.03 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 460.32.03
Kernel:  5.9.16-050916-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-modeset.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-drm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 460.32.03
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-460.32.03 DKMS files...
Building for 5.9.16-050916-generic 5.11.0-051100rc3-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.9.16-050916-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.11.0-051100rc3-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-051100rc3-generic is no
t supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-051100rc3-generic (x
86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/460.32.03/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-460 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-460 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-460:
 nvidia-driver-460 depends on nvidia-dkms-460 (<= 460.32.03-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-460 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-460 depends on nvidia-dkms-460 (>= 460.32.03); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-460 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-460 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12
) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-051100rc3-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-460
 nvidia-driver-460
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I would purge all of the Nvidia packages, rebooting, then try installing v460 again.

Comment: @ajgringo619 not worked, I did it multiple times...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll through your entire terminal output. You basically have (2) choices: downgrade your kernel, or go without the driver until one that supports v5.11 comes out. Supposedly there's a patch, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I kept getting the NVidia error but on Pop OS (and Kernel   5.11.11) I copied and pasted the error message and installed the first dependency... I got it to work.

```
`sudo apt install libnivida-gl-460`



The following packages have unmet dependencies: ` nvidia-driver-460: Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed`

                 Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-compute-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-decode-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1) but 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
                 
                 Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.67-1pop0~1616430777~20.10~71e1ad1)
```

Comment: libnivida? Is that a typo? Shouldn't it be `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460`